# New route in resource generates instead of params[:id] params[:patient_id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I added a new route to one of my resources:

```
  resources :patients do
     get 'warte'
  end
```

This generates:

```
patient_warte_path  GET     /patients/:patient_id/warte(.:format)   patients#warte
patients_path   GET     /patients(.:format)     patients#index 
new_patient_path    GET     /patients/new(.:format)     patients#new
edit_patient_path   GET     /patients/:id/edit(.:format)    patients#edit
patient_path    GET     /patients/:id(.:format)     patients#show 
.....
```

**What i dont undestand is** why the new route generated `params[:patient_id`!

I mean in my controller i have:

```
 before_action :set_patient, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :warte]

  def set_patient
  @patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
  session[:patient] = @patient.id
  end
```

But now of course i get the error: when i call the `warte` action! Thanks1

```
  Couldn't find Patient without an ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a configuration in order to have it use the `id`. You need to define if it's a `:member` or `:collection` action:

```
resources :patients do
  get 'warte', on: :member
end
```

Comment: Can you please short explain what the the difference is between member and collection? Thank you very much

Comment: There is a good explanation for nearly everything rails related on the guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html